How to compare and obtain the overlap between two columns based on their respective timestamps
I have two dataframes with the exact same two columns each: a column with as.POSIXct time, and a column with a value for each timestamp.
Here they are:
DF1:
   TIME                          OBJECT
1        1899-12-31 00:00:00     formes aimantées
2        1899-12-31 00:00:00     dinette thés
3        1899-12-31 00:00:01     dinette thés
4        1899-12-31 00:00:01     formes aimantées
5        1899-12-31 00:00:02     dinette thés
8        1899-12-31 00:00:02     boite
...

And DF2:
TIME                            OBJECT
1        1899-12-31 00:00:00     formes aimantées
2        1899-12-31 00:00:01     indéfini
3        1899-12-31 00:00:01     dinette thés
4        1899-12-31 00:00:02     boite
5        1899-12-31 00:00:02     dinette thés
8        1899-12-31 00:00:03     indéfini
...

I would like to create a third dataset with Time and the overlap between df1 and df2, to highlight when the same object is simultaneously present on both sides. The ultimate goal is to create a plot like the following, specifically the third (inferior row).

Thanks!

Are object uniques ? Or can you find them multiples times in either data frame ?
If they're unique you can just join tables (as answered below) and then create a new variable to calculate the overlapping time
Or are they ordered in both data frames ?

You can find the object multiple times, yes, at different times. However, at the millisecond precision, there is not a single timeframe that is identical on each of the tables. If we round to seconds, then yes of course many timestamps are present on both tables.

dplyr::inner_join(DF1, DF2, by = join_by(TIME, OBJECT))

